# How to sum organized array in php twig?

Tags: twig

I want to sum array in twig which has similar name. I have tried following but stuck how to sum the array.

```
                {% for job in jobs %}
                    {% if not attribute(output, job.getJobName()) is defined %}
                        {% set output = output|merge({ (job.getJobName()) : {}, }) %}
                    {% endif %}                        
                    {% set output = output|merge({(job.getJobName()) : output[job.getJobName()] | merge([job,])}) %}
                {% endfor %}
                    {% for group_title, items in output  %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ job_name }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Total Salary</td>
                            <td>{{ total_salary }}</td> //how to get total salary
                        </tr>
                        {% for item in items %}
                            {% if (item) %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ item.getEmpName() }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.getEmpSalary() }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}                        
                    {% endfor %}
```

On Dump this are the arrays

```
array:21 [▼
  0 => Model\JobItem {#3330 ▶}
  1 => Model\JobItem {#3336 ▶}
  2 => Model\JobItem {#3341 ▶}
  3 => Model\JobItem {#3584 ▶}
  4 => Model\JobItem {#3320 ▶}
  5 => Model\JobItem {#3314 ▶}
  6 => Model\JobItem {#3309 ▶}
  7 => Model\JobItem {#3303 ▶}
  8 => Model\JobItem {#3298 ▶}
  9 => Model\JobItem {#3292 ▶}
  10 => Model\JobItem {#3288 ▶}
  11 => Model\JobItem {#2845 ▶}
  12 => Model\JobItem {#2728 ▶}
  13 => Model\JobItem {#2722 ▶}
  14 => Model\JobItem {#2996 ▶}
  15 => Model\JobItem {#3004 ▶}
  16 => Model\JobItem {#2746 ▶}
  17 => Model\JobItem {#2751 ▶}
  18 => Model\JobItem {#2756 ▶}
  19 => Model\JobItem {#2765 ▶}
  20 => Model\JobItem {#2842 ▶}
]
array:2 [▼
  0 => Model\JobItem {#2858 ▶}
  1 => Model\JobItem {#2863 ▶}
]
```

What I want to achieve here is how to get total salary from each array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop the `items` another time and add all the salaries

```
{% for group_title, items in output  %}
    {% set total_salary = 0.00 %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {% set total_salary = total_salary + item.getEmpSalary() %}
    {% endfor %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{ job_name }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Salary</td>
        <td>{{ total_salary }}</td> //how to get total salary
    </tr>
    {% for item in items %}
        {% if (item) %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.getEmpName() }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.getEmpSalary() }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}                        
{% endfor %}
```